# Building UI for Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have recently started learning about building application using Spring boot. However being  new to UI , I am not sure how to write a simple UI which takes a phone number, stores at a back end and processes the data like I want to , for example send a message / push notification to the mobile number.

I looked for some tutorials which suggest to use Vaadin framework and Thymeleaf template engine. I am looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you would want to stay on top of the latest technologies regarding frameworks and Spring Boot web applications, I would recommend looking into React.js and Spring Data Rest. The following guide helped me tremendously with setting up an easy to use example:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Thymeleaf is used here so you'll also be exposed to that technology as well.

Good luck.